# Cocos2D touch event is triggered in every (unrelated) listener

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a full canvas CCLayer with several tiny CCLayers on it - they are buttons. On the buttons I enabled the touch listener:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    [self setTouchEnabled:YES];
  }
  return self;
}
```

First I tried the default touch handlers:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"This is me: %d", self->button_id);
}
```

The strange result is wherever I touch it always triggers all button touch handlers, even if I touch on a clean area, where nothing should be called.

I was reading the documentation and blogs about but nothing seemed like a straight solution. I also tried the single touch handler by adding:

```
- (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish {
  [CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

- (void)onExit {
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"This is me: %d", self->button_id);
}
```

This case the only difference was that I got only 1 listener triggered - always the one I defined the last - and again, no matter where the touch occurred.

It seems to me that the problem is not the event delegation, but the CCLayer boundaries. This is how I set the size:

```
self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Do you have ideas where I went wrong? Maybe I missed something essential.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the layer hierarchy as all touches will reach a registered node eventually.

But to save you the trouble of messing with this you can easily implement your button using the `CCMenu` and `CCMenuItem` classes.

For example :

```
 // Create a menu item with action method (when pressed) 
 CCMenuItemImage *buttonItem= [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button1.png"  selectedImage:@"button1.png" target:self selector:@selector(button1Pressed:)];

 // Create a menu with the menu item and add it to your canvas layer
 CCMenu *menu= [CCMenu menuWithItems:buttonItem, nil];
 [self addChild:menu];
```

And with this you won't need the tiny layers anymore. Just add the menu to the canvas layer and don't forget to set its menu item positions to be laid out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend going for [CCMenu](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.3/interface_c_c_menu.html) whenever you need clickable buttons. They handle `touchEvents` for you, so that you only need to concern about defining a `callBack` function. Here's a good tutorial to start with.-

http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/cocos2d-buttons-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle